# Jasmine testing: how to spy on special function?

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, jasmine, spy

I am new to Testing, Jasmine and Javascript and maybe this question is trivial. I have to test a function with Jasmine:

```
define(["module", ...], function(Module, ...){
    //...
    action: function(){
        //...
        Backbone.history.navigate('companies', {trigger: true});
        //...
    }
}
```

The test looks like this:

```
describe("function action", function() {
    it ("calls Backbone.history.navigate()", function(){
        spyOn(module, "Backbone.history.navigate");
        module.action();
        expect(Backbone.history.navigate()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

But this does not work. It says:

```
Error: Backbone.history.navigate() method does not exist
```

What do I have to do, to be able to spy on that Method?
I already tried loading the backbone.js file before running that function, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

You may write

```
spyOn( Backbone.history, 'navigate' );
```

And then

```
expect( Backbone.history.navigate ).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

A possible disadvantage to that could be, if you ever execute tests in parallel and `Backbone.history.navigate` is spied upon by one test and being used by another test, you may not have expected results.

Comment: You can tell a spy to call through to the original function with either `.andCallThrough()` or `.and.callThrough()` depending on what versjon of jasmine is used.

Comment: This is working fine for Backbone. But I tried the same thing with the custom module Session and there occurs an error: Session is not defined. What's wrong there? Session is used in module just like Backbone is...

Comment: If it says `Session is not defined`, it just means it's not available at the time of execution in the scope.

Comment: I tried to use and.callThrough() which is a very good solution. But what can I do if i want to call through a function that I don't spy on. That means in function action() there is created a new object and a function from within this object is called which causes an error. What can I do to prevent this function to be executed?

Comment: Actually I don't have much idea about your scenario. But if I may suggest something, I would say, you should spyOn all methods that you invoke from any method (in this case from `action`) and check whether that method was invoked on not from `action` - because that's what `action` method's responsibilities are. And then, whatever that called method does, should be separately checked into that called method's unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should try following

```
var backbone_historySpy=spyOn(Backbone,'history.navigate');
describe('testing function action:',function(){
it('expect Backbone.history.navigate() to be called',function(){
module.action();
expect(backbone_historySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
});
```

It should work